Outlining a Lie bracket identity for vector fields
Prove that:
$$
[f \cdot V, g \cdot W] = f \cdot V(g) \cdot W - g \cdot W(f) \cdot V + fg \cdot [V, W].
$$
We use the product rule for Lie brackets:
$$
[fV, gW] = fV(gW) - gW(fV),
$$
then we expand each term on the right-hand side (RHS) by:
$$
V(gW) = V(g)W + gV(W)
$$
and
$$
W(fV) = W(f)V + fW(V),
$$
which gives:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    & [fV, gW] = f\big(V(g)W + gV(W)\big) - g\big(W(f)V + fW(V)\big) \\
    & = fV(g)W + fgV(W) - gW(f)V - gfW(V).
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
By the antisymmetric property of Lie brackets, we get (fgV(W) = gfW(V)) leading to:
$$
[fV, gW] = fV(g)W - gW(f)V + fg[V, W].
$$
But I can't figure out what to do with that extra $- gfW(V)$ term, it would vanish, but why?
Thanks

I don't see an "extra" $- gfW(V),.$ The formula after your "leading to:" was what you wanted to show. It seems what you got wrong is to think that $fgV(W)=gf W(V),.$ No!

the point is that I just deleted -gfW(V) ...and that made the answer correct... but I don't know why it should vanish.

Deleted? Where? What you write is very confusing. Can you expand for me the term $fg[V,W]$ using the definition of the commutator? Then compare your equations.

If you compare the last and next-last equation, you will see that   $fg[V,W]$ is missing in the last, and is present in the next last.

Life would be so much simpler if you used \tag to number those equations. $fg[V,W]$ is the final term on the RHS of the last equation and equals $fg V(W)-fgW(V)$ which are two terms occuring in the equation before (presumably that's what you mean by next-last). Everything is there. Nothing missing. Nothing needs to be deleted or vanishing.

BTW: a better notation for $V(W)$ is $VW$.

By which rule do you get $fg[V,W]= fgV(W)−fgW(V)$ ?

Definition of commutator.

Thanks, that was the answer!
